# Ruby on Rails has_many polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism, associations

I have a model, Item.
Each Item has_many traits.
The traits can be many different things:
A SizeTrait
A ToppingsTrait
A FlavorTrait
etc

How can I set up this relationship in Ruby on Rails? In a normal Ruby app I could just use duck typing, but this needs to be stored the the database.

It's like the reverse of belongs_to with polymorphic: true

I would like to avoid single table inheritance as these traits, while they will share a duck type interface, will have very different functionality. This would cause a lot of unused fields in the table and that seems like a messy, confusing way of doing it.

There are a couple posts about this already on StackOverflow, but one has a different situation than mine and the other has a pretty dodgy solution, and I want to see if there's a better one.

Comment: I don't understand why not use single table inheritance to do this? If your traits will be very different functionality you have to define them in different model, right? Or are you asking how to let `@item.traits` to use the methods that defined in different model?

Comment: @Donald It seems messy because there will be lots of unused fields if all the trait models share a table. If that's the best way to do this then that's how I'll do it, but I thought there would be a better way.

Comment: @Donald Just reread your comment and would like to clarify: I absolutely do want these in different models. I just would prefer to have these models in separate tables if possible.

Comment: You want to use different models and different tables to manage traits but wants to use one dynamic association method like polymorphic, right? I think you can add a model like `Adapter`, it manage the association just like a bridge between many types of traits and item. And `Adapter` will save each trait's class name as string then you can use `Object.const_get class_name_string` to use different trait's model. If this sounds ok, I will write some example code in answer.

Comment: @Donald Thank you. That sounds right, but I am going to need to see some example code to really understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make joins across a polymorphic association.  The best approach is to just buckle down with the STI as you mentioned previously.  Although you may argue that you will have multiple fields witch will be null, at least rails will be able to make sensible joins to aid you in your queries.